# How can I apply Rem units for responsive design on React?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design

I'm changing rem units for responsive design (use rem for width and height of boxes, and change html `font-size` to make them responsive)
this works well in `html` and `css`.

However it causes a problem on React. I use media query and decrease html `font-size` to change width and height.

On React, It only works over `font-size 62.5%`. 
I can increase width and height but can't decrease them below 62.5%(10px).

App.css

```
* {
  padding:0
  margin:0px
}

html {
  font-size:6px
}
```

Other.css

```
.box1 {
   width:40rem
   height:10rem
 }
```

Comment: `//App.css
    *{
      padding:0;
      margin:0px;
    } 
    html{
      font-size:6px;
    }


//Other .css
    .box1{
       width:40rem;
       height:10rem;
     }

Comment: Setting up a demo or linking to your live code would be very helpful. Also, you can use back ticks to make your code examples more readable. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting